# How can data from a WMS Service be filtered by attribute value?

Tags: gis, arcgis, wms, sld

I am trying to filter out data from a WMS Service by the value of a certain attribute. Here is the WMS link: https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/WHSE_LAND_AND_NATURAL_RESOURCE.PROT_CURRENT_FIRE_PNTS_SP/ows?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Essentially, I am trying to filter out points with the value 'Out' for the 'Fire Status' Attribute and keep all other points with no changes. I have looked into SLD properties but I am not sure if there is an easier way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better fetching the data via a WFS (https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/WHSE_LAND_AND_NATURAL_RESOURCE.PROT_CURRENT_FIRE_PNTS_SP/ows?SERVICE=wfs&REQUEST=GetCapabilities)
and then using your client to filter the points as you want.

Alternatively, as it is a [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) you can use the vendor option to add a [CQL_FILTER](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#cql-filter) to the `getMap` request (`CQL_FILTER=%22FIRE_STATUS%22%3C%3E%27Out%27`):

```
https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/WHSE_LAND_AND_NATURAL_RESOURCE.PROT_CURRENT_FIRE_PNTS_SP/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=48.47794521980060267,-123.9759835806030424,54.47220539027199493,-117.885924731608128&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=890&HEIGHT=876&LAYERS=pub%3AWHSE_LAND_AND_NATURAL_RESOURCE.PROT_CURRENT_FIRE_PNTS_SP&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CQL_FILTER=%22FIRE_STATUS%22%3C%3E%27Out%27
```

which returns:

[image]